# Suprising gained disk space after backup & restore PostgreSQL databases

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, autovacuum

We backed up, deleted and restored several databases. Surprisingly, the databases occupy 20% less storage space afterwards. Have we lost data or what could have happened here? Autovacuum runs regularly.

Example:

```
df -h /var

pg_dump -Fc -f <file> <database>
dropdb <database>
createdb <database>
pg_restore -d <database> <file>

df -h /var
```

Answer (score 1):

You had some bloated tables or indexes in the original database.

To diagnose bloat, use the `pgstattuple` extension.

To get rid of bloat, use `VACUUM (FULL)`.

To avoid bloat, keep your transactions short, tune autovacuum to be fast enough and avoid mass deletions.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting of autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor is 0.2, so 20% empty space is entirely unremarkable when autovacuum is running as designed.